# Python sort list of lists over multiple levels and with a custom order

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.6

I have a list of lists `my_list` e.g.

```
[
['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3', 'item 3.4', 'item 3.5'],
['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2'],
['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.6', 'item 3.2'],
['item 3.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.7', 'item 2.5'],
['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.5'],
['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.4', 'item 1.5'],
['item 4.1', 'item 4.2', 'item 4.3', 'item 4.4', 'item 4.5'],
['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.5', 'item 1.5']
]
```

I want to order this list on multiple levels with 1 of the levels being a customer order but don't know how to do this.

e.g. I want to order by the first item first then within that order, order them by the third item then within that order, order by the fourth item. But I want the first item to be ordered/sorted in this particular order rather than alphabetical:

```
item 4.1
item 2.1
item 3.1
item 1.1
```

so the final list (after sorting) would be:

```
[
['item 4.1', 'item 4.2', 'item 4.3', 'item 4.4', 'item 4.5']
['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.5'],
['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2'],
['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.6', 'item 3.2'],
['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3', 'item 3.4', 'item 3.5'],
['item 3.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.7', 'item 2.5'],
['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.4', 'item 1.5'],
['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.5', 'item 1.5'],
]
```

I know I can sort over multiple levels by doing:

```
s = sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(0,2,3))
```

But this would sort them all alphabetically and what I don't know how to do is set the first column to be sorted by the custom order.

Comment: What is the source of that specific item order? Is it a list of items? Is it a mapping?

Comment: How about a `key = map(d.__getitem__, itemgetter(0,2,3)(my_list))` where `d={4.1:0, 2.1:1, 3.1:2, 1.1:3}`?

Being as sleep deprived as I am, I don't want to make my third mistake on SO for the day, but if anyone can see a way to use this, please do

Comment: The list comes from a db query and is a list of items.  They come back in the order they were added to the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugly and inefficient, but probably working:

```
order = ['item 4.1', 'item 2.1', 'item 3.1', 'item 1.1']
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: order.index(x[0]))
```

reorders `my_list` to:

```
[['item 4.1', 'item 4.2', 'item 4.3', 'item 4.4', 'item 4.5'],
 ['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.5'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3', 'item 3.4', 'item 3.5'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.6', 'item 3.2'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.7', 'item 2.5'],
 ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.4', 'item 1.5'],
 ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.5', 'item 1.5']]
```

If you want to sort by first column in a customized way, then by the third and fourth alphabetically, just expand the `key`:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: (order.index(x[0]), x[2], x[3]))
```

which returns

```
[['item 4.1', 'item 4.2', 'item 4.3', 'item 4.4', 'item 4.5'],
 ['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.5'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.4', 'item 2.7', 'item 2.5'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.6', 'item 3.2'],
 ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3', 'item 3.4', 'item 3.5'],
 ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.4', 'item 1.5'],
 ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3', 'item 1.5', 'item 1.5']]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however this doesn't seem to have done the inner orders as the order of item 3.1 is then not ordered by index 3 and 4